# Get folder next to parent folder in either Path.GetDirectory or Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net

Consider the two paths, one in a solution and the other in IIS:

Solution Path:

- C:\Users\userid\Desktop\File\Solution\RootName\ **Folder1** \Folder1a\the.aspx

IIS path

- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RootName\webApplication\ **Folder1** \Folder1a\the.aspx

Is there a way using `Directory` or `Server` or anything at all to *get the FIRST folder name after the Parent Directory?*

ie in the given above, Folder1 is the first folder after the parent folder.

I can get the opposite, which is the containing folder name from a filepath (in this example, *Folder1a*) and I can iterate it to get to the answer :

`Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));`

But the problem is, folders can be nested at any amount: (folder1a\folder1a1\folder1a1a...)

How can I get the first folder name after the Parent Directory given a file path?

**as an aside,**
If there is no foldername (ex. Folder1 does not exist) the answer should output "" (empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `..` to go to previous directory, example:

```
C:\test\..\
```

is equivalent to:

```
C:\
```

Use `Directory.GetDirectories` to find sub Directories. It has an overload where you can pass search patterns as well:

```
string[] GetDirectories(string path, string searchPattern)
```

> searchPattern
>       Type: System.String
>
> The search string to match against the names of subdirectories in path. 
>   This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal and
>   wildcard characters (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular
>   expressions.

Comment: Thank you.. but how do I get to the next directory?

Comment: Use `Directory.GetDirectories` and match your folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string filename = string.Format("{0}{1}", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Folder1\Folder1a\the.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I have tried that works.

Since I simply needed to output the first page after the word, I iterated `Path.GetDirectoryName` and `Path.GetFileName` until I could match the root folder.

Ex:

```
                baseFoldr = "";
                var curFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                string curName = Path.GetFileName(curFile);

                while (curName.ToLower() != "RootName")
                {
                        curFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(curFile);
                        baseFoldr = curName;
                        curName = Path.GetFileName(curFile);

                }

                return baseFoldr;
```

I still believe there could be a better answer, though